# What is resistivity?

Tags: solid-state-physics, temperature, electrical-resistance, definition, conductors

What is actually [resistivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_resistivity_and_conductivity)?

I read that when the temperature increases the the resistance of the conductor increase. Length and area of a material doesn't change so it means that the resistivity of the material increases with temperature in conductors.

But in semiconductors when the temperature is increased its said that resistivity is decreased.

Morever when a semiconductor goes through higher voltages which cause breakdown in semiconductors  it's resistivity decreases also.

So what exactly is resistivity and why it increases with temperature in conductors and decreases with temperature and voltage in semiconductors?

Comment: What would you accept as an answer? Would "Resistivity is to resistance just as Young's modulus is to Hooke's Law's constant of proportionality" be acceptable?

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, how would that answer the question about the difference in behavior between metals and semiconductors?

Comment: @ThePhoton it wont, but that would not be the aim of that answer anyway.

Comment: This is too broad. There are multiple questions here. Q1. What is resistivity. Q2. Why does resistivity behave differently with temperature in different materials. Q3. What is the physics of breakdown. The OP could begin with asking about good metals and Ohms law.

Answer (score 4):

Resistivity depends on two things: the number density of carriers (free charged particles) in the material, and the mobility of those carriers.

When temperature increases, the mobility decreases because of the increased density of phonons (quanta of lattice vibrational waves) in the material.

In metals, the density of carriers isn't affected much by temperature, so the resistivity is increased at high temperature due to the reduced carrier mobility.

In naturally occurring (randomly doped) or intrinsic semiconductors (such as scientists were mostly familiar with before the 1960's), high temperatures promote additional carriers to the conduction band, increasing the carrier density. This effect can be enough to overcome the reduced carrier mobility, and so the resistivity is increased.

Semiconductors with high purity and intentionally introduced dopants such as are used in modern semiconductor devices are more likely to have reduced resistivity at high temperature, like metals.

Comment: The person who is asking this is not going to see how this answer would fit into their worldview.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent, they'll have at least learned a few terms they can google or ask further questions about.

Comment: That is just infinite descent. Piling on concepts like mobility to a person thus confused would just postpone the complaint that such an activity would not bring them closer to a satisfactory understanding.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Feel free to post your own answer.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Only the OP can say if the answer is helpful to them but it may well answer the question for other readers - like me.  +1

Answer (score 1):

In both metals and semiconductors, current is the flow of (free) electrons per unit time. We typically talk about current flux, the number of charge carriers per unit area per unit time (units: C/s m$^2$ = A/m$^2$). We induce current flux $J_q$ in a material by applying a voltage across a length of the material. The voltage per unit length is the field strength $E$ (units: V/m).

The mediating materials property between the stimulus $E$ and the response $J_q$ is the electrical conductivity $\sigma$ (units: S/m or 1/ohm m or 1/mohm), giving $J_q = \sigma E$. Conductivity depends on three factors, the magnitude of the charge $Q$, the number of charge carriers per unit volume (charge number density) $\rho_{N,Q}$ (units: number / m$^3$), and the mobility of the charges $\mu$ (units: m$^2/V s).

Electrical resistivity is the inverse of conductivity $\rho = 1/\sigma$. Anything that increases conductivity decreases resistivity and *visa versa*.

When a voltage field is applied to metals or semiconductors, electrons move with a drift velocity $v_D = \mu_Q\ E$. The mobility is a measure of how freely the charges can move. The main limit to electrons moving entirely free is that they scatter from the atoms in the material. As temperature increases, the atoms vibrate more, and electron scattering increases. If resistivity was only affected by scattering, resistivity should increase in about the same manner with increasing temperature in both materials.

In both metals and semiconductors, the number density of free electrons $\rho_{N,e-}$ increases as temperature increases. In metals, the increase is fractional while in semiconductors, the increase is exponential. If resistivity was only affected by the number of free electrons, resistivity should decrease with increasing temperature, and it should decrease more strongly in semiconductors than in metals.

When the two factors are considered, the decrease in mobility of free electrons in metals wins. Resistivity increases (conductivity decreases) in metals with temperature because the free electrons scatter more and not enough free electrons are added to make up. By comparison, free electron number density wins in semiconductors. Resistivity decreases (conductivity increases) in semiconductors with temperature because, although the free electrons scatter more, more free electrons become available to make up the loss.

In a fairy-tell picture of the system, imagine the free electrons in the metal or semiconductor as ping-pong balls being pulled through a dense forest (the atoms in the lattice). As temperature increases, the trees sway more from side to side (e.g. higher temperature is like adding higher wind flow across the trees). In metals, as temperature increases, you add a few more ping-pong balls to be pulled through the swaying trees, but not enough to overcome the added scattering through the trees that are swaying harder than before. Fewer ping-pong balls get through the forest as temperature (wind cross-flow) increases. In semiconductors, you add an exponentially larger number of ping-pong balls as temperature increases. In fact, you add so many that even more get through than at lower temperature.